# VSTO How to identify parts (like a table) in a word document?

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I have multiple tables in a word template and need to change each of it in an other way. Also it is possible that one or the other will be deleted or inserted so I can't say I take the 5th and that's always the same one.
The identification has to be saved so I can't use the .ID value.

What way is there to identify a specific table with VSTO? Preferable one which can also be set in the document without VSTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

Mark the table in word and add a bookmark to it. You have to choose a unique name so you can also identify the table. The identification can be done with a method like the following:

```
public Word.Bookmark GetBookmark(String bookmarkName)
{
    // Find bookmark
    Word.Bookmark bookmark = null;
    foreach (Word.Bookmark curBookmark in Globals.ThisDocument.Bookmarks)
    {
        if (curBookmark.Name.Equals(bookmarkName))
        {
            bookmark = curBookmark;
            break;
        }
    }

    return bookmark;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem. To solve the problem I set title of the table in word tamplate(Right click table->Table Properties...->Alt text->Title) and search all the table in word document for the title. Below is the code I used to search the table.

```
public static Table getTable(Document doc, String title){
    int totalTables = doc.Tables.Count;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table ret = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalTables; i++){
        if (title.Equals(doc.Tables[i].Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
            ret = doc.Tables[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use alternative text for the tables as identifier?

Use the below code to retrieve them (code copied from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/01fa2856-2ee4-4047-840b-5e47011f0431))

```
 Word.Application wdApp = Application;
 Word.Document wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
 Word.Table wdTable = wdDoc.Tables[1];
 MessageBox.Show(wdTable.Title + "\n" + wdTable.Descr);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as both attributes are empty by default and would have to be set through code.